# How to show/hide different row sections in a JTable

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable with rows that list files and folders in a directory. The folder rows have a button that hide and show rows listing the files in the folder. When the application starts up, the files rows that come after their folder row are hidden. I used RowFilter to initially hide these rows after the table was created in a subclass method:

```
  ...

  public void createTable(){
      //Create and populate table
      ...
      //Add the filter to initially hide the subfile rows
      TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRow  Sorter<DefaultTableModel>(tableModel);
      RowFilter hidefilter = getRowFilter();
      sorter.setRowFilter(hidefilter);
      myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);                      
 }  

 ...

 private RowFilter getRowFilter() {
     RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Integer> filter = new RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Integer>() {

         @Override
         public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends DefaultTableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
             int modelRow = entry.getIdentifier();

                  if(/* current row column contains a certain flag */){
                    //Hide the row that represents a file in the folder
                    return false;
                }
                else return true;
            }
        };
        return filter;
 }
```

This code successfully hides the rows, but I'm wondering how to show and re-hide only some of the hidden rows. Can this be done with a filter class like the one I've already done? Is there a way for a filter function to be called by a button and filter based on a value found in a column?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. The filter class should have fields that store what mode it's in and the button should have an actionlistener attached, which sets the fields of your filter class. It will also have to fire an event on the table to trigger a recalculation of all the rows.

Comment: By what mode it's in, do you mean whether it's hidden or visible? Do you know how I can set those fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is that we need to have a `Filter` class that filters entries depending on the value of its fields (I only created one field to keep the example simple), and the filter also has methods that change the value of those fields.

Then we create a button that calls this method when pressed, followed by a call to `table.getRowSorter().allRowsChanged()`, which signals to the table that the data has changed so it has to redraw itself.

Here's a working example.

```
public class Test {

    public static class Filter extends RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> {
        private String includePrefix = "Foo";

        @Override
        public boolean include(
                javax.swing.RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
            return entry.getStringValue(0).startsWith( includePrefix );
        }

        // Calling this method changes the filter to allow a different prefix
        public void swapPrefix() {
            this.includePrefix = this.includePrefix.equals("Foo") ? "Bar" : "Foo";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //setup
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout( new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        JTable table = new JTable( new Object[][]{ new Object[]{ "Foo 1" },
                                                   new Object[]{ "Bar 1" },
                                                   new Object[]{ "Foo 2" },
                                                   new Object[]{ "Foo 3" },
                                                   new Object[]{ "Bar 2" }},

                                   new Object[] { "Foo"});

        //create and configure sorter
        Filter filter = new Filter();
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel());
        sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        JButton changeFilter = new JButton( "Change filter");
        // pressing the button changes the filter first, then tells the table sorter to update the display
        changeFilter.addActionListener( e -> { filter.swapPrefix(); table.getRowSorter().allRowsChanged(); });

        //display window
        frame.add( table );
        frame.add(changeFilter);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: This should do the job. Thanks!