# how hide a row from jtable if that row is boooked

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

if i am developing hotel reservation project in netbeans...
if i am having list of rooms in jtable...

```
  import java.sql.*;
  import java.text.ParseException;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Date;
  import javax.swing.*;
  `enter code here`import javax.swing.table.*; 
  import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
```

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author ssn
 */
public class welcome extends javax.swing.JFrame {`enter code here`

```
/**
 * Creates new form welcome
 */
public welcome() {
    initComponents();
    //fetch();
}
Reservation reservation = new Reservation();


Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/loginform?";
String UN = "root";
String PWD = "root";

public void fetch() {
    String sql = "select RoomNO,RoomType,BedType,RentPerDay from room";
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "UN", "PWD");
        pst = conn.prepareCall(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    From = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    To = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BookDays = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jPanel3.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("FROM");
    jPanel3.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(90, 20, 70, 30));

    From.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    jPanel3.add(From, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(171, 20, 150, 30));

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("TO");
    jPanel3.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(340, 20, 50, 30));

    To.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    jPanel3.add(To, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(401, 20, 140, 30));

    jButton1.setText("Bookingdays");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel3.add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(560, 20, -1, 30));

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "RoomNo", "RoomType", "BedType", "RentPerDay"
        }
    ));
    jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jTable1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    jPanel3.add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(40, 97, -1, 370));

    jButton2.setText("Check");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel3.add(jButton2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(590, 260, 70, 30));

    jButton3.setText("LogOut");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel3.add(jButton3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(590, 313, -1, 30));
    jPanel3.add(BookDays, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(690, 20, 70, 30));

    jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ssn\\Desktop\\New folder\\diwan3.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jPanel3.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 820, 470));

    jPanel1.add(jPanel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 820, 470));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    UserLogin UL = new UserLogin();
    UL.setVisible(true);
    dispose();// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    fetch();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    try {
        d1 = format.parse(format.format(From.getDate()));
        d2 = format.parse(format.format(To.getDate()));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    long days = hours / 24;
    BookDays.setText(Long.toString(days)+" days");


    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

int index = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();
String RoomNo = model.getValueAt(index,0).toString();
String RoomType = model.getValueAt(index, 1).toString();
String BedType = model.getValueAt(index, 2).toString();  
String RentPerDay =model.getValueAt(index,3).toString();
reservation.setVisible(true);
reservation.pack();
reservation.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
reservation.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
reservation.RoomNo.setText(RoomNo);
reservation.RoomType.setText(RoomType);
reservation.BedType.setText(BedType);
reservation.RentPerDay.setText(RentPerDay);
 // TODO add your handling code here:
         // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                    

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new welcome().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField BookDays;
private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser From;
private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser To;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

```
if i clicked one row it goes to reservation ...if i booked that room for particular days then it again it does not show that room in jtable of welcome page.

   /*
```

* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the e*/
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author ssn
 */
public class Reservation extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form Reservation
 */
public Reservation() {
    initComponents();
}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    RentPerDay = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    BedType = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    RoomNo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    RoomType = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel16 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel17 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField9 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    NoOfdays = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField11 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jComboBox3 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel2.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jLabel2.setText("RESERVATION OF ROOM");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 800, 20));

    jLabel3.setText("RoomType");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(190, 50, 60, 20));

    jLabel4.setText("RoomNo");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 50, 50, 20));
    jPanel1.add(RentPerDay, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(610, 40, 90, 30));
    jPanel1.add(BedType, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(420, 40, 100, 30));
    jPanel1.add(RoomNo, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 40, 80, 30));
    jPanel1.add(RoomType, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(260, 40, 100, 30));

    jLabel5.setText("RentPerDay");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(540, 50, -1, 20));

    jLabel6.setText("BedType");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(370, 50, -1, 20));

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setText("CustomerName");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 110, 100, 20));

    jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel8.setText("CustomerID");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 160, 90, 20));

    jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel9.setText("IDProof");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(410, 100, 80, 30));

    jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel10.setText("Proof_No");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(410, 160, 70, 20));

    jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel11.setText("Address");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel11, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 200, 50, 30));

    jButton1.setText("Logout");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 20, -1, -1));

    jLabel12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel12.setText("City");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel12, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 250, 50, 30));

    jLabel13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel13.setText("State");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel13, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 310, 50, 20));

    jLabel14.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel14.setText("NoOfPersons");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel14, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(410, 210, 90, 20));

    jLabel15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel15.setText("Purpose");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel15, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(410, 340, 80, 20));

    jLabel16.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel16.setText("MartialStatus");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel16, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 360, 110, 20));

    jLabel17.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel17.setText("NoOfDays");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel17, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(410, 280, 80, 20));

    jButton2.setText("Book");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(jButton2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(520, 383, 70, 30));
    jPanel1.add(jTextField1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 100, 130, 30));

    jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(jTextField2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 150, 130, 30));
    jPanel1.add(jTextField3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 200, 130, 30));
    jPanel1.add(jTextField7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(530, 90, 120, 30));
    jPanel1.add(jTextField8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(530, 150, 120, 30));

    jTextField9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField9ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(jTextField9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(530, 200, 120, 30));

    NoOfdays.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            NoOfdaysActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(NoOfdays, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(530, 270, 120, 30));
    jPanel1.add(jTextField11, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(530, 330, 120, 30));

    jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Select", "Married", "Single", " " }));
    jPanel1.add(jComboBox2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 350, 130, 30));

    jComboBox3.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Select", "Andhra Pradesh ", "Arunachal Pradesh ", "Assam ", "Bihar", "Chhattisgarh ", "Goa ", "Gujarat ", "Haryana ", "Himachal Pradesh ", "Jammu & Kashmir ", "Jharkhand ", "Karnataka ", "Kerala ", "Madhya Pradesh ", "Maharashtra ", "Manipur ", "Meghalaya ", "Mizoram ", "Nagaland", "Odisha ", "Punjab ", "Rajasthan ", "Sikkim ", "Tamil Nadu ", "Telangana", "Tripura ", "Uttarakhand ", "Uttar Pradesh ", "West Bengal ", " " }));
    jPanel1.add(jComboBox3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 300, 130, 30));
    jPanel1.add(jTextField4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 250, 130, 30));

    jLabel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 204));
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ssn\\Desktop\\New folder\\living_room_800.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jPanel1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 800, 430));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
welcome wl = new welcome();
wl.setVisible(true);
 dispose();// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

// JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(null,"Rooom Booked Sucessfully");        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

```
private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jTextField9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void NoOfdaysActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
// String NOofdays  = wel.g  // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reservation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reservation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reservation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reservation.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Reservation().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public javax.swing.JTextField BedType;
private javax.swing.JTextField NoOfdays;
public javax.swing.JTextField RentPerDay;
public javax.swing.JTextField RoomNo;
public javax.swing.JTextField RoomType;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox2;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel16;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel17;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField11;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField9;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

```
enter code here
```

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: Why did you delete the previous question on this exact same question? You've already been given the answer!

Comment: yes but that makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to add a Booking table or add a booking Boolean to your room database. When the room is booked skip over that row and do not add it to your table.

Comment: Or you can use a filter, this answer has a good example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886010/how-to-show-hide-different-row-sections-in-a-jtable